# SingleChildScrollView вызывает сильное торможение

Tags: flutter, dart

У меня есть экран приложения на нем должен отображаться длинный список элементов, изначально за скролл элементов отвечал `ListView.builder`. Но по мере нарастания приложения получилось так что на этом же экране мне понадобилось разместить другие виджеты, например поисковая строка. По умолчанию `ListView`занимает всю область экрана для отрисовки элементов списка, я включил свойство `shrinkWrap: true` и отключил физику скролла у самого `ListView`. И обернул полностью весь виджет который подгружает на экран элементы в `SingleChildScrollView` для того чтобы можно было на этом же экране разместить другие виджеты:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
         child:Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
            ProductHeader(),
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(10)),
            Product() // Здесь вызывается список элементов
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Место где вызывается `ListView.builder`:

```
class Product extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<ProductController>(
      init: ProductController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.productList.value,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    ProductCards(
                  // index: index,
                  product: snapshot.data[index],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Когда на экране отображается около 30 элементов списка, торможений не замечено, но когда я попытался вывести больше 1000 элементов, началось жуткое торможение. Причем если скроллом занимается непосредственно сам `ListView.builder` и список занимает всю область экрана торможений нет.

В общем торможение вызывается насколько понял из за того что я отключаю скролл на самом `ListView` и передаю этот скроллинг другому виджету `SingleChildScrollView`.

**Есть какие идеи из за чего это может происходить, возможно у меня допущены какие либо ошибки?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось что нужно было всего то сделать такую обертку `Expanded` -> `Container`-> `ListView.builder`, тогда ListView.builder не будет занимать всю область экрана и можно будет смещать его любым образом. Данный способ не нуждается в подключении свойства `shrinkWrap = true`, так как скроллом элементов в данном случае будет заниматься сам `ListView.builder`.

Пример исправленного кода, класс `Product`:

```
class Product extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<ProductController>(
      init: ProductController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.filterProduct.value,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        ProductCards(
                      // index: index,
                      product: snapshot.data[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Класс `Body`:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(10)),
          ProductHeader(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          Product()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Не сразу заметил `shrinkWrap: true,` в вопросе... Да такой вариант ответа тоже приемлемый.

Answer (score 0):

SingleChildScrollView рендерит все виджеты в child. Также вложенность scroll виджетов в друг друга влияют на производительность. По этому и происходит просадка при 1000 элементов.

Решение вашей проблемы это использовать [sliver](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers) виджеты. Вот небольшой пример как это должно быть:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text('Test'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20)),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              return Material(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(index.toString()),
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: 100,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Я так понял sliver это выдвижной AppBar, и просто виджеты которые мне нужно выстроить поверх списка уместить в этом AppBar?
И если это AppBar, то влияет ли он на текущий, который задается из Scaffold, заменяет или что с ним делает?

Comment: `Sliver` это не "выдвижной AppBar", это скролл виджед. `ListView` работает на основе `Sliver`. В него вы можете добавить `SliverAppBar`, который будет заменять `AppBar` из `Scaffold`.

Comment: Хм, очень интересно, завтра попытаюсь применить его, проверю насколько удобна будет его реализация

Comment: Попытался применить `sliver` виджеты вместо `SingleChildScrollView`, он мне показался крайне не удобным в отличии от того же `SingleChildScrollView`, которым просто обернул `Column` и всё. Перестал работать поиск элементов и самое главное торможение осталось таким же как и было. Пока что единственное что более менее работает это `ListView.builder` в чистом использовании, элементы которого не обернуты в `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Для того что бы использовать любой виджет не относящийся к `sliver` пришлось оборачивать в `SliverToBoxAdapter`, даже обычный `SizedBox`. А список элементов `Card`, которые генерируются в `ListView.builder` я обернул в `SliverList`, не помогло.